Proving representibility of some functor in Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book.
I want to understand proof of next proposition ( Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 8.4. )

Proposition8.4. Let $S$ be a scheme and let $v : \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F}$ be a homomorphism of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules.
(2) Let $\mathcal{F}$ be finite locally free. Then the locus $v=0$ is closed ; i.e., the functor
$$ F : (\mathrm{Sch}/S)^{\mathrm{opp}} \to (\mathrm{Sets}),  \ F(T)= \{ f \in \mathrm{Hom}_S(T,S) ; f^{*}(v)=0\} $$
is represented by a closed subscheme of $S$.

Proof. If $\mathcal{F}$ is finite locally free, we have $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})= \check{\mathcal{E}} \otimes \mathcal{F} = \check{( \mathcal{E} \otimes \check{\mathcal{F}})} $ by $(7.5.4).$ Thus $v$ corresponds to a homomorphism $\bar{v} : \mathcal{E}\otimes \check{\mathcal{F}} \to \mathcal{O}_S$ of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules. Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the image of $\bar{v}$. Then $\mathcal{J}$ is a quasi-coherent ideal of $\mathcal{O}_S$. If $f: T\to S$ is a morphism, then $f^{*}(v)=0$ if and only if $f^{*}(\bar{v})=0$. But $f^{*}(\bar{v})=0$ if and only if the ideal $\mathcal{I}$ generated by $\mathcal{J}$ in $\mathcal{O}_T$ is zero, which happens if and only if $f$ factors through the closed sucscheme $V(\mathcal{J})$
Here $V(\mathcal{J})$ means the closed subscheme induced from quasi-coherent ideal $\mathcal{J}$, called the vanishing scheme of $\mathcal{J}$ ; C.f. Gortz's book p.196.
I don't understand the bold statement at all. First of all, what is the definition of 'the ideal $\mathcal{I}$ generated by $\mathcal{J}$ in $\mathcal{O}_T$' ? I guess this object as follows : Let $j : \mathcal{J}:=\mathrm{im}(\bar{v}) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_S$ be the inclution. Then it induces $f^{*}(j) : f^{*}\mathcal{J} \to f^{*} \mathcal{O}_S=\mathcal{O}_T$. Then $\mathcal{I}$ is defined its image $\mathrm{im}(f^{*} j) \subseteq \mathcal{O}_T$. Note that $V(\mathcal{I})=f^{-1}(V(\mathcal{J}))$ ( $\because$ Ideal of the pullback of a closed subscheme ). ( This fact may used in the final statement of the proof )  Am I guessing well?
And, again back to the main topic, why
$$ f^{*}(\bar{v})=0 \ \Leftrightarrow  \ \mathcal{I}=0 $$
? I am strugling with this stuff with hours. Can anyone help?

When you refer to a source, please give the names of all authors. In this case: Görtz and Wedhorn.

@ Lazzaro Campeotti : O.K. Yes :)

O.K. First, note that $\mathcal{I} := \mathrm{im}(f^{*} j) =0$ if and only if $f^{*} j=0$. So it suffices to show that $f^{*}(\bar{v})=0$ if and only if $f^{*}j=0$.
But second, it is true by For $f: T\to S, v : \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_S$ and $j :\mathrm{im} (v) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_S$, $f^{*}(v)=0$ if and only if $f^{*}(j) =0$?  .
